# giving a default value for an angular number formcontrol

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working with angular. I am astonished that we cannot give an empty default value for an angular number formcontrol. At the beginning, I set it to 0, but it isn't my requirement, since my input display 0 before entering anything. It must be a solution

Comment: No I mean FormGroup<Bean>({
    numberPropertyOfBean: new FormControl(0,[Validators.required]),

Comment: Can you take the example at [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uuwnca?file=src/app/app.component.html), fork it, and add your code

Comment: Also if you pass `undefined` or `''` instead of `0`, what happens?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `FormControl` in a reactive form using an empty value, empty string, or even `undefined`:

Component:

```
foo = new FormControl();
```

Template:

```
<input type="number" [formControl]="foo" />
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uuwnca?file=src/app/app.component.html) in action that demonstrates the number input being initialized without any value.

Hopefully that helps!